# use fully qualified names in utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

I want to launch utop in a directory containing `a.ml` (which has a definition for `something`) and be able to enter `A.something` in utop. I know I can do `#use "a.ml"`, but that pollutes the global namespace. How can I make the fully qualified name `A.something` work in utop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `#help`:

```
#mod_use <str>
  Usage is identical to #use but #mod_use wraps the contents in a module.
```

So `#mod_use "a.ml"` should do it.